# Error Build on Production Server of Jhipster Project

Tags: java, maven, jhipster

I generate a project use jHipster, when I build the project in terminal with this command "mvn -Pprod package", I get error about node and yarn. Tomorrow I must show this project to my lecture.

This is error messages :

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.github.eirslett:frontend-maven-plugin:1.4:install-node-and-yarn (install node and yarn) on project myapp: Could not extract the Yarn archive: Could not extract archive: '/home/andrew/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/0.27.5/yarn-0.27.5./yarn-v0.27.5.tar.gz': EOFException -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException

Please anyone help me solve this problem.

Thank you.

Comment: Looks like your archive got corrupted. Delete this folder and you should be ok: /home/andrew/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/0.27.5/

Comment: ok. .successfull. .thank you so much @Andrei

Answer (score 3):

This was solved by the #1 comment:

`Looks like your archive got corrupted. Delete this folder and you should be ok: /home/andrew/.m2/repository/com/github/eirslett/yarn/0.27.5/`

Comment: Thank you very much @Julien Dubois